# Closing a redirected console in WINAPI from another thread

Tags: c++, winapi, io, console

So I have created a console in Win32 beside by main OpenGL window in order to use it to generate commands for my event loop. However, I am having some difficulties. The console is repeatedly checking for cin input, using the following loop:

```
while (*loopEnabled)
{
    string str;
    getline(cin, str);

    if (str == "quit")
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return;
    }
}
```

This is running in a separate thread from my main window, and is meant to send the quit event and exit. However, first of all, the quit message does not seem to work entirely. What seems to happen is that this only allows the main window to be closed - i still need to close the main window manually. It seems that PostQuitMessage does not throw the appropriate Windows event for me to process? Perhaps I'm making some mistake here.

A much more profound problem is actually quitting this event loop from outside of the console thread without me having to enter random input for it to move past the constant getline and quit when the condition fails. I tried to do this by attempting to feed in fake input, but I was unable to do this. It may have something to do with the inputs being redirected to the console. Maybe exceptions may work? I do not know.

Here's the code that redirected the io to the console:

```
AllocConsole();

handleOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
int hCrt = _open_osfhandle((long)handleOut, _O_TEXT);
hfOut = _fdopen(hCrt, "w");
setvbuf(hfOut, NULL, _IONBF, 0); //Can assign custom buffer here! Currently no buffering (_IONBF)
*stdout = *hfOut;

handleIn = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
hCrt = _open_osfhandle((long)handleIn, _O_TEXT);
hfIn = _fdopen(hCrt, "r");
setvbuf(hfIn, NULL, _IOLBF, 256);
*stdin = *hfIn;
```

Summary:
I have window and console. I close window, it waits for console input to get that getline in the loop. I type "quit" in the console, and the console loop ends but the main window doesn't notice. Help? .-. I'm rather new to Windows programming.

Comment: Wrong thread, every thread has its own message queue.  You'll have to PostMessage() the WM_QUIT message.  And of course know what window to post it to, never a minor detail in a worker thread that wants to mess with the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

[`PostQuitMessage()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644945.aspx) posts a `WM_QUIT` message to the message queue of the thread that is calling it.  Your console loop runs in its own thread, so your main window running in a different thread will never receive the `WM_QUIT` message.  To post a `WM_QUIT` message to a window in another thread, use [`PostMessage()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944.aspx) instead.

`std::getline()` does not exit until the user types a line of text into the console.  As you have seen, that does not allow you to terminate the console thread.  `std::cin` does not tell you when text is available for reading, so you do not have the option to call `std::getline()` only when there is something to read.  Try switching to [`ReadConsole()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684958.aspx) or [`ReadConsoleInput()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684961.aspx) instead.  Then you can use [`WaitForSingleObject()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032.aspx) to detect when there is input ready to be read.  That will give you an opportunity to monitor the thread for any termination conditions in between each read, such as a boolean variable.  Alternatively, use a waitable [event object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682655.aspx) to signal termination, then you can use [`WaitForMultipleObjects()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025.aspx) to wait for termination and input at the same time, and it will tell you which signal to act on.